# Issue connecting via SSH to Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: bash, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I was doing a project through Azure and it required me connecting via SSH. I did the whole thing and it worked perfectly fine. I am trying to connect now but whenever I enter "ssh demouser@" it gives me the error: 
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Does anyone know why I might be getting this error or how I can fix it? I want to be able to SSH into my Virtual Machines.

Comment: Have you configured an endpoint in your Azure VM which allows SSH connection?

Comment: Are you adding the hostname after the @ sign?

Comment: Yes i have and after the @ sign im putting my IP. It used to work fine.

Comment: can you do `ssh root@localhost`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset the SSH connection to the VM:
In the classic mode it can be done in the portal - click on "Reset remote access". In the Azure Resource Manager mode it can be done using cli (or powershell):

```
azure config mode arm
azure vm reset-access -g TestRgV2 -n TestVmV2 -r
azure vm extension set "testRG" "testVM" VMAccessForLinux Microsoft.OSTCExtensions "1.2" --private-config-path PrivateConf.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned it worked perfectly fine, I'm assuming you were able to connect through SSH previously.

The error you posted indicates a client-side error. To make sure there aren't any special characters when you copy-paste the ip/hostname (from portal?), can you try to create the ssh command in a text editor and then copy-paste the entire command from the editor?